# Getting wrong User ID from self._uid

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, uid

I'm trying to get the logged in user's id from self._uid. But when I logged in with a user and I got the user_id = 1 (which is the user_id of the administrator account)

That is my line. Am I doing something wrong?

user_id = self._uid

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

from

```
user_id = self._uid
```

to

```
user_id = self.env.user
```

These will give us current logged user as a recordset. So if you need `id`, get it like `self.env.user.id`

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, I mean I'm getting the same user_id (which is one, the administrator's id) though I logged in with a different user.